# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (python) not sure how to resolve this issue

Tags: python

The main function gives me an error, not sure how I can fix this, and some explanation as to what is happening in this error will be much appreciated.
I tried to input in the entry field a random position in this format "28.834592°  -46.099829°" without quotes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes


window = tk.Tk()
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32


# Main Function
def main():
    lat = input_coordinate()[0]
    long = input_coordinate()[1]
    print(lat,long)



def input_coordinate():
    try:
        user_coordinates = lat_long_Entry.get()
        # print (user_coordinates)
        new_user_coordinates = user_coordinates.replace("°"," ")
        new_coordinates = new_user_coordinates.split(" ",1)
        #print (new_user_coordinates)
        coordinates = []
        counter = []
        for item in new_coordinates:
            coordinates.append(float(item))
        #print (coordinates)
        for i in range(len(coordinates)):
            counter.append(i)
        #print (counter)
        if (coordinates[0] is str) or (counter[0] is None) or (counter == [0]):
            print("fail")
        else:
            print("Success")
            return coordinates
    except ValueError:
        popupmsg_nocoordinate()



def popupmsg_nocoordinate():
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Error")
    label = tk.Label(popup, text="Please Enter a Valid Coordinates in decimal degree !", font="NORM_FONT")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B4 = tk.Button(popup, text="Cancel", command=popup.destroy)
    B4.pack()
    popup.mainloop()



# label fields
window.title("Scale Calculator")
window.geometry('350x350')
Title = tk.Label(text="Calculator")
lat_long = tk.Label(text="Enter Coordinates")

lat_long_Entry = tk.Entry()

run = tk.Button(text="Run", command=main)


lat_long.grid                   (row=1, column=0, )

lat_long_Entry.grid             (row=1, column=2, )
run.grid                        (row=5, column=0, )


window.mainloop()
```

I feel this is not the most optimized way to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I entered the same input and it printed `Success` and the coordinates. Are you sure that this is the case? And which line throws the error above?

Comment: sorry, my explanation was not so clear, what i wanted to say is that when i enter any value  that is non decimal single integer, i get the error. "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Don\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 11, in main
    lat = input_coordinate()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: That is because you're expecting two different coordinates, latitude and longitude in order to split them in `"°"` and get the separate values in a list. Since you do not insert the character which is used for splitting, a list cannot be created (which is a subscritable object) and thus, you cannot use indices such as `[0]` to access its elements. Could you provide an input example in which the above error orrurs? For instance, is it happening when you just enter an integer?

Comment: As an example you could add 123, yes the error is only whe you have a single integer